# Qt destructor call for closed widget

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, destructor

There is application that handles text commands. I have a Qt widget that is closed with some `close *` command. `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute is set for that widget, it receives closeEvent, but destructor for that object is called later (I guess on idle). If I have two commands
`close *; get something;` the program crashes because `get something` is called before destructor for that widget, so it tries to access data deleted by `close *` command. How can I force Qt to call destructors? `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` after close command doesn't help.
I've got this problem after changing qt version to 4.7.2 from 4.3.3. There is no multithreading here.

Thanks in advance.

**added**

Here is the code example.

```
test *t = new test();
t->show();
std::cout << "before deleteLater()" << std::endl;
t->deleteLater();
std::cout << "after deleteLater()" << std::endl;
QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents();
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
std::cout << "after processEvents()" << std::endl;
```

test class is derived from QDialog. It prints `test()` in constructor and `~test()` in destructor. This code gives the following output

```
test()
before deleteLater()
after deleteLater()
after processEvents()
~test()
```

According to Qt documentation it should delete the object before last cout, am I right? Looks like a bug in Qt, does anybody know anything about it? Any workaround?

I asked the question in Qt mailing list, but still waiting for an answer.

Thanks.

**one more update**

This code

```
Dialog::~Dialog() {
    std::cout << "~test()" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Dialog* dlg = new Dialog();
    dlg->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    dlg->show();
    dlg->close();
    std::cout << "before sendPostedEvents()" << std::endl;
    QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents();
    std::cout << "after sendPostedEvents()" << std::endl;
    return app.exec();
}
```

prints this

```
before sendPostedEvents()
after sendPostedEvents()
~test()
```

but as soon as I add closeEvent handler and call deleteLater() in that handler function sendPostedEvents starts deleting deferred objects.

```
void Dialog::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* ev) {
    deleteLater();
    QWidget::closeEvent(ev);
}
```

prints this
    before sendPostedEvents()
    ~test()
    after sendPostedEvents()

Can anybody explain what the hell is going on there? Is it just a bug? Can I use that as a workaround?

How does this work? Shouldn't Qt call deleteLater() automatically, after closeEvent is accepted if CloseOnDelete attribute is set?

Comment: Please, could you put some update here if you will find a solution. I have the same problem and I am really curious how it could be solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting [`Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) means qt can delete anytime after you call [`close()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#close) because qt uses [`deleteLater()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) internally. You can ensure the deletion using [`QObject::destroyed()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) signal.

Comment: I was able to fix it by adding deleteLater() function call for that widget in closeEvent function. But I would like to understand the solution. Could you please explain that in more details or provide a link that explains that technique?

Comment: I want to ensure that Qt will delete the at the moment I finished executing my first command. How can I make it?

Comment: If you can close it you can delete it too. Don't set `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` flag and simply delete it. You'll be sure then.

Comment: The application is really huge, then I would need to ensure that I delete it from everywhere where close is called. I wouldn't like to make much changes there. This might result in memory leak. Isn't it possible to force Qt to delete the objects marked as DeleteOnClose?

Comment: According to qt documentation, you can use `sendPostedEvents()` too. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents

Comment: processEvents() and sendPostedEvents() doesn't help. If I switch to manual deletion it works fine, but when I replace `delete obj` with `obj->deleteLater(); QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents();` or processEvents() it doesn't work again.

Comment: Manual deletion does not result memorly leaks if code is properly written. Normally `processEvents` should delete that object. Because `deleteLater` sends an event to widget and calling `processEvents` with no argument should handles all posted events. It can be a bug in qt. I think you should write this problem to qt-interest@qt.nokia.com maillist.

Comment: It can result to memory leak, because I'm not sure where it can be closed from, to put delete everywhere. And yes, code is not properly written :) I'll try nokia forums. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

QCoreApplication::processEvents explicitly skips delete on close events.  You need to pass QEventLoop::DeferredDeletion to processEvents().  i.e. QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::DeferredDeletion);