# How to capture the QDockWidget close button click event

Tags: c++, qt, qdockwidget

I have a `QStackedWidge`t within a `QDockWidget` - depending on which page is shown I wish to show/hide the close button on the `QDockWidget`. I can do this by using `QDockWidget::setFeatures()`.

However the issue I'm facing is how to capture the signal of the close button so that I can change the dock features / set the stacked widget page index.

[image: QDockWidget close button]

I have attempted to use an event filter:

```
class EventFilter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    EventFilter( QObject* aParent );
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
};

EventFilter::EventFilter( QObject* aParent )
    : QObject( aParent )
{

}

bool EventFilter::eventFilter( QObject *obj, QEvent *event )
{
    if ( event->type() == QEvent::Close )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter( obj, event );
}
```

And installed it as so:

```
EventFilter* filter = new EventFilter( this );
u->dockWidget_6->installEventFilter( filter );
```

In the constructor of my `QMainWindow` - the `eventFilter()` method did not get called.

So next I attempted to use the `QDockWidget::visibilityChanged` changed signal since it sounded like this might be what I wanted:

```
connect( u->dockWidget_6, SIGNAL(visibilityChanged(bool)), SLOT(dockWindowClosed(bool)) );
```

This slot did get called - but not when the close button was clicked.

Finally I attempted to use a promoted `QDockWidget` to capture the `QWidget::closeEvent()`.

```
  class DockWidgetWithCloseSignal : public QDockWidget
  {
       Q_OBJECT
   public:
      explicit DockWidgetWithCloseSignal(const QString &title, QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0)
        : QDockWidget( title, parent, flags )
    {

    }

    explicit DockWidgetWithCloseSignal(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0)
 : QDockWidget( parent, flags )
    {

    }
protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
    {
        event->ignore();
    }
};
```

I saw the constructor was called which means this new widget was indeed being used, but again no joy since the `closeEvent()` was never called when the close button was clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that everything apart from the `visibilityChanged` signal works!

I added a signal to the overridden `closeEvent()` method which I could then connect to any slot I wanted.

The actual issue was that within the stacked widget I had another `QDockWidget` on another page, hence I was adding all of these things to the wrong `QDockWidget`! (And of course promoted the wrong `QDockWidget` too doh!).

Hopefully this question can serve as a reference to anyone else that needs to figure out how to do this - rather than why it isn't working.

Comment: I've used QObject::destroyed() signal as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091830/qt-destructor-call-for-closed-widget

Answer (score 3):

Create a new CloseDockWidget based on DockWidget.

Override the closeEvent() method, but emit an additional closed() signal from there.

**widgets/qclosedockwidget.cpp**:

```
#include "qclosedockwidget.h"

namespace Widgets
{
    QCloseDockWidget::QCloseDockWidget(const QString &title, QWidget *parent) 
    : QDockWidget(title, parent)
    {
        // constructor
    }

    void QCloseDockWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
    {
        emit closed(); // <------ signal

        QDockWidget::closeEvent(event);
    }
} // namespace Widgets
```

**widgets/qclosedockwidget.h**:

```
#ifndef QCLOSEDOCKWIDGET_H
#define QCLOSEDOCKWIDGET_H

#include <QDockWidget>

namespace Widgets
{

    class QCloseDockWidget : public QDockWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        QCloseDockWidget(const QString &title = "", QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    protected:
        void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);
    signals:
        void closed();
    };

} // namespace Widgets

#endif // QCLOSEDOCKWIDGET_H
```

Now you are able to instantiate and connect to the new signal:

```
auto *dockWidget = new Widgets::QCloseDockWidget("MyDockWidget", this);

connect(dockWidget, &Widgets::QCloseDockWidget::closed, this, &MainWindow::dockWidgetCloseClicked);
```